# How to make function to accept filename as an argument in node js

Tags: node.js

The function in the following code will always read test.txt it is not a shared function, how to make it as a shared function

```
var readFile = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
        if (error){
            reject(error);
        }else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
});

module.exports.readFile = readFile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this
**readFileFunction.js**

```
var ReadFile= function(fileName) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
        if (error){
            reject(error);
        }else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
});
}

module.exports = ReadFile;
```

To use this function
**someOtherFile.js**

```
var ReadFile = require('./readFileFunction.js') // correct path to readFile
ReadFile(fileName).then(function(data) {
  /* stuff */
})
```

**For your code**

```
-nodeapp
--helper.js
--main.js
--text.txt
--readFileFunction.js
```

Say you need to read File in main.js. 
in **main.js**

```
 var ReadFile = require('./readFileFunction.js')
 // other code
 ...
 // you need to read text.txt
var fileName1= 'text.txt' //change name according to your wish here
var fileName2= 'text2.txt' //change name according to your wish here


 ReadFile(fileName1).then(function(dataOfFile1) {
    ReadFile(fileName2).then(function(dataOfFile2) {
      /* your file stuff */
      console.log(dataOfFile1) // all your file data
      console.log(dataOfFile2) // all your file data
    })
```

})

Hope this will help

Comment: @DuskyDood where ever you want to use that function. Second code is actually the function call to readFile. Use it anywhere you want

Comment: Hy the code is in a folder called nodeapp and it contain helper.js, main.js and test.txt for the above code where i should mention the test.txt file

Comment: @DuskyDood I updated my ans. Is it now helpful to you? Please Ask if any doubt.

Comment: ReadFile(fileName).then((message) => {
^

Comment: @DuskyDood please check you are importing that function by correct path and file name.

Comment: ReadFile(fileName).then(function(data) {
^
TypeError: ReadFile is not a function

Comment: @DuskyDood my bad. In first code snippet use `module.exports = ReadFile;` insted of `module.exports.readFile = ReadFile;`

Comment: -main.js--

var ReadFile = require('./helper.js')

var fileName= 'sometext.txt' 
ReadFile(fileName).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});

Comment: if i have to two text file and to read it one after another what should i do

Comment: is possible to make async waterfall instead of .then

Comment: yes yes. For that you might need to do some setup. So visit https://medium.com/@_bengarrison/javascript-es8-introducing-async-await-functions-7a471ec7de8a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186233/discussion-between-dusky-dood-and-rajan-lagah).